# How to hide the block title?

Tags: theming

We have a block on some pages which we like it without title, but when using < none > or leave it blank, it just showing the page title on the block title !

So how can we hide the block title ?

Comment: Is the block created using views?

Comment: @Vamsi On admin => Structure => Blocks => Add a new block

Comment: Okay. How you are creating the block. Using views or using code.

Comment: @Soheyl So, there should be a Two titles, One on page which is original page title and one one Block, which is also a page title?, Right?

Comment: @Vamsi if by views u mean admin panel, yes I do like that :)

Comment: @CodeNext Well I have a block title on the block configuration page !

Comment: Please provide the following facts, So it gets more clear (1) Your block is placed in which region? i.e. first-sidebar, second sidebar, content etc? (2) *it just showing the page title on the block title !*, if you say so, it means that, at the place of block-title, page-title takes place, right? (3) If you can, please post the image snap-shot, so everybody gets clear idea of what is the issue?. (4) Are you using D7 or D8?

Comment: @CodeNext the block is in the content region, sorry, but I can't provide any link or screenshot because of the client policy !

Comment: @Soheyl, i have added the answer, please check thoroughly, is that your issue?

Comment: @CodeNext THX, check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Rishi](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3808/rishi-kulshreshtha) answer is perfect for hiding the block-title and it should work.

From your question, I can guess you are confusing the page title with the block title, or you want to hide the page title and the block title.

Let me give you an example. I created a page where I show a simple block with its body (four lines). The page has just its title.

In the following screenshot, I didn't hide the block title, so both the page and block title appear.

> [image]

In the following screenshot, I hide the block title, so only the block body appears, together the the page title. Hence, it looks like the block title is replaced by the page title. Is this your issue?

> [image]

First you need to understand, how pages and blocks work. They are two completly different things.

Now, I placed the trial block in the content region as shown in the following screenshot, which shows the page, with its title and content. After that, it  shows the block with its title and content.

> [image]

Hiding the block title setting it to `<none>` in the block configuration page  works fine: It hides the block title as shown on the second screenshot from top. At this stage, it looks like the page title takes the place of the block title, and hiding the block title is not working. And that is your question. So, this myth is totally wrong. The page title is there, where it was. The block title got hidden by `<none>`, and the block body is where it should be.

Your question should be how to hide both the page and the block title.

For the block title, you can use `<none>`.
For the page title, you need the [Exclude node title](https://www.drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title) module, which is the module I used to hide the page title as shown in the following screenshot.

> [image]

The following screenshot shows the page after hiding block and page title.

> [image]

See the differences between the first, second, and fifth screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

In the *Block title* field, use `<none>` to display no title. Go to     admin/structure/block/manage/system/main/configure: You will find the following description.

> Override the default title for the block. Use `<none>` to display no title, or leave blank to use the default block title.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the block title is easy, using CSS styles. You can add them with the [CSS Editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_editor) module.

```
.block-title {
    display: none;
}
```

That will remove all the block titles. So if you want your block to have a custom title, you have to put it in the block, instead of using the block title, or block description when you create your blocks.